# Create/update with Sequelize on an array of items

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird, sequelize.js

I created a function to:

- take an array of 'labels' and look for whether they have a record in the db already
- create those which don't exist,
- and update those which do exist
- return a json array reporting on each item, whether they were updated/created, or resulted in an error

I managed to make it work but I feel like I just made some ugly dogs' dinner!

```
var models = require("../models");
var Promise = models.Sequelize.Promise;

module.exports = {

    addBeans: function (req, callback) {

        Promise.map(req.body.beansArr, function (bean) {
            return models.Portfolio.findOrCreate({where: {label: bean}}, {label: bean});

        }).then(function (results) {   // Array of 'instance' and 'created' for each bean "findOrCreate(where, [defaults], [options]) -> Promise<Instance>"
            var promisesArr = [];
            results.forEach(function (result) {
                if (result[1]) {   // result[1] = wasCreated
                    promisesArr.push(Promise.resolve([result[0].dataValues.label, "created"]));   
                } else {
                    promisesArr.push(
                        models.Portfolio.update({label: result[0].dataValues.label},
                            {where: {label: result[0].dataValues.label}}).then(function () {
                                return Promise.resolve([result[0].dataValues.label, "updated"])
                            })
                    );
                }
            }); 
            return promisesArr;

        // When it's all done create a JSON response
        }).then(function (results) {
            var resultObj = {items: []};  // JSON to return at the end
            Promise.settle(results).then(function (promiseinstances) {

                for (var i = 0; i < promiseInstances.length; i++) {
                    if (promiseInstances[i].isFulfilled()) {
                        resultObj.items.push({
                            item: {
                                label: promiseInstances[i].value()[0],
                                result: promiseInstances[i].value()[1],
                                error: ''
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else if (promiseInstances[i].isRejected()){
                        resultObj.items.push({
                            label: promiseInstances[i].value()[0],
                            result: 'error',
                            error: promiseInstances[i].reason()
                        });
                    }
                }

            // Send the response back to caller
            }).then(function () {
                return callback(null, resultObj);
            }, function (e) {
                return callback(e, resultObj);
            });

        });
    }

};
```

Question:

- Is there an easier or more obvious way to create/update values with Sequelize?
- Is my use of `Promise.settle()` appropriate for this case? I have the feeling I made this more complicated than it needs to be.

I am new to Sequelize and using Promises, I'd appreciate if someone could advise on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like this would work better on CodeReview.SE but I can see a few issues.

> Is there an easier or more obvious way to create/update values with Sequelize?

Well, for one thing:

```
.then(function(array){
   var newArr = [];
   array.forEach(function(elem){
       newArr.push(fn(elem);
   }
   return newArr;
});
```

Is just

```
.map(fn)
```

Additionally, promises assimilate so you can `return val;` from a `.then` you don't have to `return Promise.resolve(val);`.

So:

```
).then(function (results) {   // Array of 'instance' and 'created' for each bean "findOrCreate(where, [defaults], [options]) -> Promise<Instance>"
    var promisesArr = [];
    results.forEach(function (result) {
        if (result[1]) {   // result[1] = wasCreated
            promisesArr.push(Promise.resolve([result[0].dataValues.label, "created"]));   
        } else {
            promisesArr.push(
                models.Portfolio.update({label: result[0].dataValues.label},
                    {where: {label: result[0].dataValues.label}}).then(function () {
                        return Promise.resolve([result[0].dataValues.label, "updated"])
                    })
            );
        }
    }); 
    return promisesArr;
})
```

Is just

```
.map(function(result){
     if(result[1]) return [result[0].dataValues.label, "created"];
     return  models.Portfolio.update({label: result[0].dataValues.label},
                    {where: {label: result[0].dataValues.label}}).
                    return([result[0].dataValues.label, "updated"]);
 });
```

However, since you want it to work regardless of it being resolved, you'd have to do:

```
.then(function(results){
     return results.map(function(result){
     if(result[1]) return [result[0].dataValues.label, "created"];
     return  models.Portfolio.update({label: result[0].dataValues.label},
                    {where: {label: result[0].dataValues.label}}).
                    return([result[0].dataValues.label, "updated"]);
 });
 });
```

Which means it'll resolve regardless, then you'd call `.settle()`:

```
.settle().then(function(results){
     // your settle logic here
});
```

Note that the last:

```
}).then(function () {
    return callback(null, resultObj);
}, function (e) {
    return callback(e, resultObj);
});
```

Is simply:

```
.nodeify(callback);
```

However, I recommend sticking to promises.

Comment: Thanks a million! One question: What do you mean 'promises assimilate'? I though with 'return val;' I pass 'val' as an argument to the function unwrapped with 'then' (e.g.: .then(function(val){}); ), and with 'Promise.resolve(val)' I pass the promise?

Comment: Promise.resolve will be called implicitly on everything you return in `then`.

Answer (score 0):

I use Promise.settle for sequelize.update, and can get affect rows number by _settledValueField .

```
promise.push(...update...)

db.sequelize.Promise.settle(promise).then(function (allresult) {
    var affectcnt = 0
    allresult.forEach(function (singlecnt) {
      if (undefined !== singlecnt._settledValueField[1]) {
        affectcnt += parseInt(singlecnt._settledValueField[1])
      }
    })
```

unfortunately, it's only work for update.

Comment: It looks like partial answer. Please try to consolidate it into complete answer

Answer (score 0):

You can insert array in database using sequelize. You want to change in model like below. I am trying to add multiple languages in database through array.

```
language: { type: DataTypes.STRING, 
          allowNull: false,
          get() 
         { 
         return this.getDataValue('language').split(';') 
         }, 
        set(val)
        {
        this.setDataValue('language',Array.isArray(val) ? val.join(','):val);

      }
  }
```